# object value not being updated correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I have an object as follows:

```
{
"headerSection": {
    "text": "Some Text",
    "color": "red",
    "fontSize": "12px",
    "backgroundColor": "#000",
    "textAlign": "left"
   }
}
```

I have a dropdown list which users can choose a different font size i.e. `14px, 16px .. 20px`. On the change event of this dropdown I want to change the value of `fontSize` in my above object so for that I do:

```
$('#font-size-ddl').change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    headerObj.fontSize = value;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(headerObj));
});
```

In the above `console.log` the output is:

```
{
"headerSection": {
    "text": "Some Text",
    "color": "red",
    "fontSize": "12px",
    "backgroundColor": "#000",
    "textAlign": "left"
 },
"fontSize": "20px",
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is `headerObj` here?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay `headerObj` is my object which gets returned to me from the server exactly how I have mentioned in the question

Comment: I have answered for your issue.

Comment: Hope you got the solution @code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update `headerSection` **fontSize** property.

In your case the compiler looking after `fontSize` property of your `headerObj` object, it don't found it and create a new **property** for your object.

```js
let headerObj={
"headerSection": {
    "text": "Some Text",
    "color": "red",
    "fontSize": "12px",
    "backgroundColor": "#000",
    "textAlign": "left"
   }
}

$('select').change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    headerObj.headerSection.fontSize = value;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(headerObj));
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="20px">20px</option>
  <option value="30px">30px</option>
</select>
```

Comment: My apologies, you were the first one to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, after looking at your output, that the `fontSize` property is being improperly appended.

You need to do this to add it under `headerSection`.

```
$('#font-size-ddl').change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    headerObj.headerSection.fontSize = value; // like this
    console.log(JSON.stringify(headerObj));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#font-size-ddl').change(function () { 
    var value = $(this).val(); 
    headerObj.headerSection.fontSize = value;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(headerObj));
 });
```

you're adding a value to headerObj instead of headerObj.headerSection, as you can see from the console.log

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested object. An unnested object would look like this

```
{
"text": "Some Text",
"color": "red",
"fontSize": "12px",
"backgroundColor": "#000",
"textAlign": "left"
}
```

Instead you have an outside object, with a property called "headerSection" pointing at another object. If you're not going to change your data structure, then you need to change your code to access the inner property. Something like this

```
$('#font-size-ddl').change(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  headerObj["headerSection"]["fontSize"] = value;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(headerObj));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok then you just need to make a little change.

```
$('#font-size-ddl').change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    headerObj.headerSection.fontSize = value;  // See here.
    console.log(JSON.stringify(headerObj));
});
```

Comment: Your welcome. Happy to help. You can accept the answer too. TYIA